# Magento 2 Custom cache for top menu

Tags: magento2, cache, topmenu

I want to create custom cache for top menu

For this I have created `cache.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Cache/etc/cache.xsd">
    <type instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Cache\Vmenu" name="vmenu_cache_tag" translate="label,description">
        <label>vmenu</label>
        <description>My Menu</description>
    </type>
</config>
```

Also created Model/Cache/Vmenu.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Cache;
class Vmenu extends \Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope
{
    const TYPE_IDENTIFIER = 'vmenu_cache_tag';
    const CACHE_TAG = 'VMENU_CACHE_TAG';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool $cacheFrontendPool
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool $cacheFrontendPool
    ) {
        parent::__construct($cacheFrontendPool->get(self::TYPE_IDENTIFIER), self::CACHE_TAG);
    }
}
```

Now my vmenu.phtml is calling from header.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Theme::html/vmenu.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

My question is, how can I connect vmenu.phtml to my newly created cache?

Answer (score 2):

you can also see this post https://www.optiweb.com/blog/magento-2-custom-cache-type/,   I already create the module and I just need to associate the topmenu and the Cache save/loa function, thanks.